# Limit of f(x)=5 as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

Hi I have the following question from my homework sheet:

"find $L ∈ R$ such that $f(x)$ tends to $L$ as $x → ∞$. prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to∞} f(x) = L$ from the definition of a limit.

(The definition of the limit I used was $(∀\epsilon > 0) (∃K \in R) (∀x \in X) x > K ⇒ |f(x) − L| < \epsilon.)$

$f : R → R, x → f(x) := 5$
So far I said:

$L=5$ as $x$ tends towards infinity and the proof I said was:
Let $\epsilon>0$

$|f(x)-5|<\epsilon$

$|5-5|<\epsilon$

$0<\epsilon$

So where would I go from here i.e. how would I find $K$?
Many thanks

Comment: As $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ is always true, $K=42$ can do.

Comment: Would any value do?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: i'd say any K greater or equal to zero

Comment: Why this artificial constraint ? I don't see a trace of that in the definition.

Comment: So any K in R will be good